# Start stop function on scroll event within if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, scroll

I have a script which animates a headline.

I am trying to make this script fire on page load, but if a user scrolls more than 200px, I'd like this function to stop.

Below is my animated headline script, and also my scroll/if else statement. This should fire the `wordAnimate()` function on page load, but stop if user scrolls more than 200px. There is also some classes being added and removed conditionally in the scroll for a sticky navbar that appears after the 200px scroll.

JS:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  return (scroll < 200) && $(window).wordAnimate(); 
  if (scroll >= 200) {
    $('.logo').removeClass('transparent').addClass('opaque');
  }
  else {
    $('.logo').removeClass('opaque').addClass('transparent');
  }
});
```

**animate-headline.js**:

```
function wordAnimate() {
    //set animation timing
    var animationDelay = 2500,
        //loading bar effect
        barAnimationDelay = 3800,
        barWaiting = barAnimationDelay - 1000, //3000 is the duration of the transition on the loading bar - set in the scss/css file
        //letters effect
        lettersDelay = 50,
        //type effect
        typeLettersDelay = 150,
        selectionDuration = 500,
        typeAnimationDelay = selectionDuration + 800,
        //clip effect 
        revealDuration = 600,
        revealAnimationDelay = 1500;

    initHeadline();


    function initHeadline() {
        //insert <i> element for each letter of a changing word
        singleLetters($('.cd-headline.letters').find('b'));
        //initialise headline animation
        animateHeadline($('.cd-headline'));
    }

    function singleLetters($words) {
        $words.each(function(){
            var word = $(this),
                letters = word.text().split(''),
                selected = word.hasClass('is-visible');
            for (i in letters) {
                if(word.parents('.rotate-2').length > 0) letters[i] = '<em>' + letters[i] + '</em>';
                letters[i] = (selected) ? '<i class="in">' + letters[i] + '</i>': '<i>' + letters[i] + '</i>';
            }
            var newLetters = letters.join('');
            word.html(newLetters).css('opacity', 1);
        });
    }

    function animateHeadline($headlines) {
        var duration = animationDelay;
        $headlines.each(function(){
            var headline = $(this);

            if(headline.hasClass('loading-bar')) {
                duration = barAnimationDelay;
                setTimeout(function(){ headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('is-loading') }, barWaiting);
            } else if (headline.hasClass('clip')){
                var spanWrapper = headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper'),
                    newWidth = spanWrapper.width() + 10
                spanWrapper.css('width', newWidth);
            } else if (!headline.hasClass('type') ) {
                //assign to .cd-words-wrapper the width of its longest word
                var words = headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper b'),
                    width = 0;
                words.each(function(){
                    var wordWidth = $(this).width();
                    if (wordWidth > width) width = wordWidth;
                });
                headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper').css('width', width);
            };

            //trigger animation
            setTimeout(function(){ hideWord( headline.find('.is-visible').eq(0) ) }, duration);
        });
    }

    function hideWord($word) {
        var nextWord = takeNext($word);

        if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
            var parentSpan = $word.parent('.cd-words-wrapper');
            parentSpan.addClass('selected').removeClass('waiting'); 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                parentSpan.removeClass('selected'); 
                $word.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden').children('i').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
            }, selectionDuration);
            setTimeout(function(){ showWord(nextWord, typeLettersDelay) }, typeAnimationDelay);

        } else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('letters')) {
            var bool = ($word.children('i').length >= nextWord.children('i').length) ? true : false;
            hideLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, bool, lettersDelay);
            showLetter(nextWord.find('i').eq(0), nextWord, bool, lettersDelay);

        }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
            $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ width : '2px' }, revealDuration, function(){
                switchWord($word, nextWord);
                showWord(nextWord);
            });

        } else if ($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('loading-bar')){
            $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').removeClass('is-loading');
            switchWord($word, nextWord);
            setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(nextWord) }, barAnimationDelay);
            setTimeout(function(){ $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('is-loading') }, barWaiting);

        } else {
            switchWord($word, nextWord);
            setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(nextWord) }, animationDelay);
        }
    }

    function showWord($word, $duration) {
        if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
            showLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, false, $duration);
            $word.addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden');

        }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
            $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ 'width' : $word.width() + 10 }, revealDuration, function(){ 
                setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, revealAnimationDelay); 
            });
        }
    }

    function hideLetter($letter, $word, $bool, $duration) {
        $letter.removeClass('in').addClass('out');

        if(!$letter.is(':last-child')) {
            setTimeout(function(){ hideLetter($letter.next(), $word, $bool, $duration); }, $duration);  
        } else if($bool) { 
            setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(takeNext($word)) }, animationDelay);
        }

        if($letter.is(':last-child') && $('html').hasClass('no-csstransitions')) {
            var nextWord = takeNext($word);
            switchWord($word, nextWord);
        } 
    }

    function showLetter($letter, $word, $bool, $duration) {
        $letter.addClass('in').removeClass('out');

        if(!$letter.is(':last-child')) { 
            setTimeout(function(){ showLetter($letter.next(), $word, $bool, $duration); }, $duration); 
        } else { 
            if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) { setTimeout(function(){ $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('waiting'); }, 200);}
            if(!$bool) { setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, animationDelay) }
        }
    }

    function takeNext($word) {
        return (!$word.is(':last-child')) ? $word.next() : $word.parent().children().eq(0);
    }

    function takePrev($word) {
        return (!$word.is(':first-child')) ? $word.prev() : $word.parent().children().last();
    }

    function switchWord($oldWord, $newWord) {
        $oldWord.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
        $newWord.removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('is-visible');
    }
}
```

What is a better way to do this?
Currently myFunction won't fire unless I call it from the debugger in the browser dev tools.

**UPDATE:**
Problem solved by adding a `stopAnimating()` and `restartAnimating()` function to the large, animated headline script. This way we can call those specific functions from within the scroll if/else.

**JS:**

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (scroll >= 200) {
        $('.nav-wrapper').removeClass('transparent').addClass('opaque');
        stopAnimating();
      }
      else {
        $('.nav-wrapper').removeClass('opaque').addClass('transparent');
        restartAnimating();
      }
    });
```

animate-headline.js:

```
//set animation timing
var stop
var animationDelay = 2500,
  //loading bar effect
  barAnimationDelay = 3800,
  barWaiting = barAnimationDelay - 1000, //3000 is the duration of the transition on the loading bar - set in the scss/css file
  //letters effect
  lettersDelay = 50,
  //type effect
  typeLettersDelay = 150,
  selectionDuration = 500,
  typeAnimationDelay = selectionDuration + 800,
  //clip effect 
  revealDuration = 600,
  revealAnimationDelay = 1500;

 initHeadline();


function initHeadline() {
  //insert <i> element for each letter of a changing word
  singleLetters($('.cd-headline.letters').find('b'));
  //initialise headline animation
  animateHeadline($('.cd-headline'));
  stop = false;
}

function stopAnimating() {
  stop = true;
}

function restartAnimating() {
  stop = false;
}

function singleLetters($words) {
  $words.each(function(){
    var word = $(this),
      letters = word.text().split(''),
      selected = word.hasClass('is-visible');
    for (i in letters) {
      if(word.parents('.rotate-2').length > 0) letters[i] = '<em>' + letters[i] + '</em>';
      letters[i] = (selected) ? '<i class="in">' + letters[i] + '</i>': '<i>' + letters[i] + '</i>';
    }
      var newLetters = letters.join('');
      word.html(newLetters).css('opacity', 1);
  });
}

function animateHeadline($headlines) {
  var duration = animationDelay;
  $headlines.each(function(){
    var headline = $(this);

    if(headline.hasClass('loading-bar')) {
      duration = barAnimationDelay;
      setTimeout(function(){ headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('is-loading') }, barWaiting);
    } else if (headline.hasClass('clip')){
      var spanWrapper = headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper'),
        newWidth = spanWrapper.width() + 10
      spanWrapper.css('width', newWidth);
    } else if (!headline.hasClass('type') ) {
      //assign to .cd-words-wrapper the width of its longest word
      var words = headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper b'),
        width = 0;
      words.each(function(){
        var wordWidth = $(this).width();
          if (wordWidth > width) width = wordWidth;
      });
      headline.find('.cd-words-wrapper').css('width', width);
    };

    //trigger animation
    setTimeout(function(){ hideWord( headline.find('.is-visible').eq(0) ) }, duration);
  });
}

function hideWord($word) {
  var nextWord = takeNext($word);

  if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
    var parentSpan = $word.parent('.cd-words-wrapper');
    parentSpan.addClass('selected').removeClass('waiting'); 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      parentSpan.removeClass('selected'); 
      $word.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden').children('i').removeClass('in').addClass('out');
    }, selectionDuration);
    setTimeout(function(){ showWord(nextWord, typeLettersDelay) }, typeAnimationDelay);

  } else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('letters')) {
    var bool = ($word.children('i').length >= nextWord.children('i').length) ? true : false;
    hideLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, bool, lettersDelay);
    showLetter(nextWord.find('i').eq(0), nextWord, bool, lettersDelay);

  }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
    $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ width : '2px' }, revealDuration, function(){
      switchWord($word, nextWord);
      showWord(nextWord);
    });

  } else if ($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('loading-bar')){
    $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').removeClass('is-loading');
    switchWord($word, nextWord);
    setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(nextWord) }, barAnimationDelay);
    setTimeout(function(){ $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('is-loading') }, barWaiting);

  } else {
    switchWord($word, nextWord);
    setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(nextWord) }, animationDelay);
  }
}

function showWord($word, $duration) {
  if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) {
    showLetter($word.find('i').eq(0), $word, false, $duration);
    $word.addClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden');

  }  else if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('clip')) {
    $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').animate({ 'width' : $word.width() + 10 }, revealDuration, function(){ 
      setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, revealAnimationDelay); 
    });
  }
}

function hideLetter($letter, $word, $bool, $duration) {
  $letter.removeClass('in').addClass('out');

  if(!$letter.is(':last-child')) {
    setTimeout(function(){ hideLetter($letter.next(), $word, $bool, $duration); }, $duration);  
  } else if($bool) { 
    setTimeout(function(){ hideWord(takeNext($word)) }, animationDelay);
  }

  if($letter.is(':last-child') && $('html').hasClass('no-csstransitions')) {
    var nextWord = takeNext($word);
    switchWord($word, nextWord);
  } 
}

function showLetter($letter, $word, $bool, $duration) {
  $letter.addClass('in').removeClass('out');

  if(!$letter.is(':last-child')) { 
    setTimeout(function(){ showLetter($letter.next(), $word, $bool, $duration); }, $duration); 
  } else { 
    if($word.parents('.cd-headline').hasClass('type')) { setTimeout(function(){ $word.parents('.cd-words-wrapper').addClass('waiting'); }, 200);}
    if(!$bool) { setTimeout(function(){ hideWord($word) }, animationDelay) }
  }
}

function takeNext($word) {
  if(stop == true) {
    return $word.parent().children().eq(0);
  }
  else {
    return (!$word.is(':last-child')) ? $word.next() : $word.parent().children().eq(0);
  }
}

function takePrev($word) {
  return (!$word.is(':first-child')) ? $word.prev() : $word.parent().children().last();
}

function switchWord($oldWord, $newWord) {
  $oldWord.removeClass('is-visible').addClass('is-hidden');
  $newWord.removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('is-visible');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  return ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) && $(window).myFunction(); 
});
```

The function will only execute under `200px` scrollTop position.

### JS Fiddle Demo

---

**Edit** Updated with your code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  return (   scroll < 200
          && $(window).wordAnimate()
          && $('.logo').removeClass('opaque').addClass('transparent')
         )
      || $('.logo').removeClass('transparent').addClass('opaque'); 
});
```

Comment: the function does not seem to be executing when I try to implement this. The only way i can get the function to execute is by putting myFunction(); into the console

Comment: Does my demo do what you wanted to do, but not your implementation? If so, please add code that you have and could be relevant.

Comment: i updated my original question with more info and updated code

Comment: I appreciate your help. This isn't working either however. The wordAnimate() function is not firing on page load, and when I scroll back to the top, my transparent class is not being applied to .logo